# Is it true that a graph with many edges has a long route?

Tags: graph-theory

Is the following sentence true or not?

If we have a graph with $n$ vertices, and $e$ edges, if $e > 100 n$, then we always have a $100$-long route in the graph.

I think it is true, I tried to use that $2e = \sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i$, which means that the average degree for a vertex is at least $200$. Can't really go forward. Any help? :)

**Edit:** Answer below.

Comment: What if you say something like: If we didn't have a $100$-long route, then each connected component should have less than $100$ elements (i.e. $n_i<100$). Then, the total number of edges would be less than $\sum_i\binom{n_i}{2}<50(n_1+\cdots +n_k)<100n$ ? What exactly do you mean by route? Are we allowed to walk through the same vertex twice?

Comment: We can't pass the same vertex twice :)

Comment: @Theo, it is not true that if a graph has no route of length $L$, then each connected component has fewer than $L$ vertices. Think about the letter Y as a graph with 4 vertices, but no route of length 4.

Comment: Your probably already noted this, but using  $e \leq \binom{n}{2}$ and $e>100n$, you get $n > 200$. So, these have to be big graphs. More than $200$ vertices, and more than $100 \cdot 200 = 20000$ edges. Not much hope of drawing some small examples to get a feel for it! Maybe set $100 = 2$... :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, my comment doesn't apply if we are not allowed to pass through the same vertex twice; I thought I shouldn't delete the comment, since Atvin clarified the situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I got the answer:

The average degree is $200$, if all of them are over $100$, I am done, because I can just use one of them as starter: $v_1$ and this vertex has at least $99$ neighbours. Choose one of them(not $v_1$), let it be $v_2$, this one has at least $98$, and so on, in this way, I get my $100$-long route.

If some of the degrees are lower than $100$, delete them from the graph until all of the degrees are over $100$. The graph won't get empty since the average is $200$. I can use what I proved above for the remaining graph.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Kinda strange that I need to answer my own, but the answer is so nice that I had to post :)